# Limit superior of a discontinuous function

Tags: analysis

I just a have problem regarding a definition i found here on limit superior of a function at a point.

Definition of limsup of function ( i found it here on math exchange) :
\begin{equation}
\limsup _{x\rightarrow x_{0} ;x\in E} f(x)=\inf\Bigl\{\sup \bigl\{f(x):x\in E\land |x-x_{0} |< \delta \bigr\} :\delta \in \mathbf{R}^{+}\Bigr\} \tag{A}
\end{equation}

the following are equivalent (for $L\in \mathbb R$):

1. $\displaystyle \limsup _{E\ni x\rightarrow x_{0}} \ f( x) =L$
2. For every $\displaystyle \epsilon  >0$ and every sequence $\displaystyle ( x_{n}) \subset E-\{x_{0} \}$ converging to $\displaystyle x_{0}$, there exists $\displaystyle N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\displaystyle n\geq N\Longrightarrow $$\displaystyle f( x_{n}) < L+\epsilon $ and $\displaystyle f( x_{m})  >L -\epsilon $ for infinite $\displaystyle m$.

But i have an example for which I can't seems to figure it out

[here is the function i defined in desmos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DM2q.jpg)

By above definition, limsup at 2 is 3 right? So, we can find a sequence for example (1.9, 1.99, 1.999...) which converges to 2 from left but there exist epsilon let's take if 0.1 such that $\displaystyle f(x_{m})$ doesn't exceed 3 - 0.1 for any m or doesn't exceeds infinitely, so $\displaystyle f( x_{m})  >L -\epsilon $ for infinite $\displaystyle m$
doesn't hold, can someone help me with this, what i am missing etc.

Ps: my first time posting here, so please excuse me for any silly mistakes.

Comment: (2) is wrong. It is not true for *every sequence*, but rather, for every $\epsilon$, there exists a sequence having this property. Also, (2) is not the "definition". The definition is (A). (2), when properly stated, is a *theorem* that can be proved from the definition. Alternatively, you could consider (2) to be the definition, and (A) a theorem provable from it.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Ohh thanks man for clearing my doubt, also pointing out that definition and theorem mistake will be careful in future.